# Hyper-V virtual machine unable to get IP address from DHCP server running on same physical box

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, dhcp, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, dhcp-server

We have a Windows server 2008 R2 with two network cards running AD, DHCP, DNS and Hyper-V

The first nic is setup with a static IP address and DHCP, WDS, and DNS are bound to it.

The second nic is configured in Hyper-V to be only used by Hyper-V and has been automatically configured so that only the virtual switch is enabled on the adapter.

DHCP and DNS work fine for all physical machines on the network. It also works for Virtual Machines running on another physical box.

Virtual machines that are bound to the virtual switch network adapter are unable to get a IP address. If the virtual machine is given a static IP address with correct subnet, gateway and dns everything works.

Has anyone else got this working?

Answer (score 0):

I would give the second NIC a static IP too

Comment: Even though the other hyper-v server is configured this way? What will the static IP do for me if the adapter is just a bridge?

Comment: I would rather have a static IP address for the management network card and a static address for the virtual network card. I can easily configure this on a bare metal install and I am not reliant on DHCP and DNS to be working to get connected.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, two dedicated NICs work fine like that.

A common mistake though is to configure link aggregation on the uplink switch. (Static) LAG causes the switch to *not* forward between the ports, causing exactly the problem you describe. Simply remove the LAG from the server ports, unless you're properly bonding the NICs on the host side as well.